How are the baud rate and cutoff frequency related to each other?
I am confused about the relationship between the cutoff frequency of a low-pass filter and the baud rate. From my understanding, the baud rate can be the same as the bandwidth of a signal, but this depends on the type of modulation applied to the signal.
Let's say I am using GNU Radio to receive a signal from a mini-satellite like CIRBE, which operates with a baud rate of 19.2k, uses FSK modulation, and has a downlink frequency of 437.250 MHz. To receive this signal, I use an SDR that samples at 2.5 Msps. I can apply a Frequency Xlating FIR Filter to decimate and use it as a low-pass filter. Let's say I decimate by 40, and then for the Low-Pass Filter taps block, I set the cutoff frequency to slightly higher than double the baud rate, like 40 kHz. But I don't understand why the cutoff frequency has to be related to the baud rate. Is it because the baud rate equals the bandwidth? Does this depend on the type of modulation? For example, would the same approach apply to S-NET C, which transmits with a 1.2k AFSK downlink (435.950 MHz)?

The bandwidth at the output of the FSK modulator depends on several parameters:

the baud rate
the delta frequency $f_\Delta = f_u - f_l$ or equivalently the modulation index.
the type of modulation, e.g., discontinuous-phase or continuous-phase FSK
the use of pulse shaping on the modulating signal

I searched but could not find these parameters for the CIRBE satellite you described.
Couch [1, p.342] discusses the approximate transmission bandwidth based on Carson's rule as follows:
$$B_T = 2f_\Delta + 2B$$
where $B$ is the bandwidth of the modulating signal. If the modulating signal is lowpass-filtered at $f_b = 1/T_b$ (where $f_b$ is the baud rate), then this becomes
$$B_T = 2f_\Delta + 2f_b$$
If $f_\Delta$ is small compared to the baud rate, then its contribution is negligible and you can approximate $B_T = 2f_b$.
By the way, you may be interested in my upcoming presentation on FM and FSK systems at the DSP Online Conference, https://dsponlineconference.com/session/Improved_Binary_FSK_Carrier_Offset_Tracking_using_Model-Based_Parameter_Estimation
[1] Digital and Analog Communication Systems, Leon~W.~Couch, 1993, fifth, Prentice Hall (couch)

Hi, your explanation is exactly what I needed. So, if I want to do the same for, let's say, the UWE-3 CubeSat https://www.pe0sat.vgnet.nl/satellite/cube-nano-picosats/uwe-3/ , which operates at 437.385 MHz (downlink), 9k6 baud, and FSK, I would set the cutoff frequency at 21,120 Hz to satisfy BT > 2f_b, right? By the way, when is your conference? It would be awesome to hear more about it!

@ed190: Thanks, I am glad it was helpful.
As long as $f_\Delta << f_b$ you can use the $B_T \approx 2f_b$ rule. I'm not sure where you got the specific number 21,120 Hz, but that should work; anything greater than $2f_b = 19200$ Hz.
Details on the DSP Online Conference: link
--Randy

Details on the DSP Online Conference

Perfect! Well, the value of 21,120 Hz was obtained by multiplying 9600 * 2.2 which I thought had to be greater than 2f_b.
